# C fscanf strangely concatenating two strings

Tags: scanf

This program is really getting on my nerves:

I am trying to read a line from a file with following information:

```
512 MB 136.186.99.1 00-25-B3-0B-31-29
```

which is in the format of `double string string string`

and the code I'm using is

```
fscanf(filePtr, "%lf %s %s %s", &Computer[i].ram, Computer[i].ram_unit, Computer[i].MACNo, Computer[i].IPV4);
```

but when I print `Computer[i].ram_unit` I get:

```
MB136.186.99.1
```

Please help me to find out what I'm doing wrong. Let me know if you like me to paste the entire code.

Thanks

Comment: Please paste the definition of Computer and the struct containing ram and ram_unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have `MACNo` and `IPV4` reversed in your `fscanf` relative to the sample input.

Can't tell for sure without seeing the structure definition, but it looks like a possible array overrun.  For example, if your `Computer` was defined like this:

```
struct ComputerType {
    double ram;
    char ram_unit[2];  /* This needs to be 3 (assuming unit is always 2 chars long) */
    char IPV4[16];
    char MACNo[17];
};
```

when you read "MB" into `ram_unit`, you could end up having

```
ram_unit[0] = 'M'
ram_unit[1] = 'B'
IPV4[0] = '\0'
```

And then when you read in the IP address into IPV4 that makes it

```
ram_unit[0] = 'M'
ram_unit[1] = 'B'
IPV4[0] = '1'
IPV4[1] = '3'
[etc]
IPV4[10] = '1'
IPV4[11] = '\0'
```

When you go to print out `ram_unit`, the print function will start at the memory location `&ram_unit[0]` and keep on printing until it sees a `NULL`.  But since the `NULL` ended up in `IPV4[0]` and that got overwritten when you read in the IP address, it won't stop printing until it gets to the NULL at `IPV4[11]` and so you get the unexpected concatenation.

Comment: Quantum Mechanic - Thank you so much, you just saved the day

Answer (score 0):

To read a line from a file like this one:

> 1603 Lu,Ma,Mi,Ju,Vi,Sa,No Mar del Plata           08:25 09:20 Aerolineas Argentinas

Use this:

```
fscanf(pf, "%d %2s,%2s,%2s,%2s,%2s,%2s,%2s %[^\n]s %d:%d %d:%d %[^\n]s",
    &registro.code,
    &registro.dia.lunes,
    &registro.dia.martes,
    &registro.dia.miercoles,
    &registro.dia.jueves,
    &registro.dia.viernes,
    &registro.dia.sabado,
    &registro.dia.domingo,
    &registro.destino,
    &registro.hSalida.hh,
    &registro.hSalida.mm,
    &registro.hLlegada.hh,
    &registro.hLlegada.mm,
    &registro.aerolinea
);
```